# Converting a list of base 10 integer into list of base 4 in python

Tags: python, list

First of all I am sorry if the title did not correct.
I am trying to build a program which convert a list of base 10 integer into its binary string.For example I have this list

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

and I want to convert it into base 4. Perhaps it should look like this

```
b4 = [[00],[01],[02],...[33]]
```

Below is what I've wrote so far

```
def base10base4(pix,b):
       pix = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
       for i in range(pix):
              digits = []
              while pix > 0:
                     digits.insert(0, pix % b)
                     pix = pix // b
print(base10base4(pix[i], 4))
```

When I run this code it give me error like this

```
NameError: name 'pix' is not defined
```

I am still very new in Python. Did I miss something or I need to change the whole code? I am using Python 3.5
Thank you for the help

Comment: You need to define `pix` outside your `base10base4()` function.

Comment: There's more problems that that in your code. The `base10base4` does not actually return anything anyway. And why do you do `for i in range(pix)`? The loop will basically convert all numbers less than `pix` to quaternary (base4) and then throw away the result.

Comment: thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

This is a recursive function that returns a list of strings of base b representations of the integers in your list

```
def convertToBase(num,base):
    q=num/base
    r=num%base
    if (q == 0):
        return str(r)
    else:
        return convertToBase(q,base) + str(r)

pix = [0,3,15,56,12,34] #the list of numbers you want converted to base b
print [convertToBase(x,4) for x in pix]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. by " assuming the list contains number from 0 to 15 only", did you mean if the list have number more than 15 this code will not work?

Comment: I'm sorry...it seems that your code here returned the result in decimal

Comment: mr @Kaustav Datta do i have to add something if i want to change the base for numbers more than 15?

Comment: No I had written the previous code trying to make minimal change to your code to show you where you went wrong, and how it could be fixed. I have edited the above code where I've written a generalised function to convert a num to any base.